# PHP mailer not error but message not send

Tags: php, phpmailer, form-submit

I want to know if there is any bad in my code or if a I need to buy a email server SMTP,I need recommendations of email server SMTP with hosting web very cheap, Godaddy has a offer hosting web fort 2.29$/month but i don't now if include email server

```
//This file is in folder
//The file class.phpmailer.php with the file smtp.php is in a folder called "include" inside the previous folder.

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            $Asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
            $Nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $Mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
            $Archivo = $_POST['archivo'];
            $emailf = $_POST['correo'];
            $sujeto = "Sitio Web";
            require ("includes/class.phpmailer.php");
            $mail = new phpmailer();
            $mail->PluginDir = "includes/";
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
            $mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
            $mail->Port = "25";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "micorreo"; 
            $mail->Password = "micontrasena";
            $mail->From  = "micorreo";
            $mail->FromName = "Sitio Web"; 
            $mail->Timeout=30;
            $mail->AddAddress($emailf, $Nombre);            
            $mail->Subject = $sujeto; 
            $mail->Body = " ASUNTO: $Asunto\n NOMBRE: $Nombre\n MENSAJE: $Mensaje\n $Archivo\n";
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Send();
        }
?>
```

Comment: Turn on SMTP Debugging: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging and you might get some clues.

Comment: `$mail->From` should be an email address.

Answer (score 0):

php does not need `<br>` to break the line. remove all of them.

if you want to break line in the mail content, place it **inside** the quote.

example

```
$mail->body = "Lorem ipsum <br> dolor sit amet";
```

that should works. php is not the same as html.

Comment: The OP seemed to have added the HTML here on SO, to try and format the question.